# Protecting Java data (saving items to a secure file)?

Tags: java

I am making a simple text game in Java and I wanted a safe way to save statistics (money, etc).

I could do a text file but then it could just be modified. I was wondering if there was a simple way to make it a little more difficult for someone to mess around with the saved statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializing might be a simple solution. Store the data that needs to be saved into a Serializable class (Look up the java Serializable interface) and write it to a file. It won't be uber-encrypted, but it'll stop people from just opening it up in notepad and changing it.

Here's a simple example of how to serialize an object to a file; googling around should produce more if needed.
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0075.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in stopping people modifying the contents of the file (but don't care if they are able to read it), then have a look at using SHA1 to generate a simple signature for the file so you can tell if anyone has tampered with it.

That way anyone who opens it can see what's inside, but they can't modify it without you knowing (as the content will not match attached signature).

If you want full encryption of the file, that's doable too. Google something like `java encryption` to see more.

Pseudo code would look something like:

```
public class SignedFileSaver {

  private static final String SECRET = "Y0UR_S3CR3T_HERE";

  public void save(String content, String fileName) {
    String signature = sha1(content + SECRET);
    String signedContent = content + "\n----END CONTENT----\n" + signature;
    writeFile(content, fileName);
  }

  public String load(fileName) {
    String signedContent = readFile(fileName);
    String content = signedContent.whateverTextIsBefore("\n----END CONTENT----\n");
    String signature = signedContent.whateverTextIsAfter("\n----END CONTENT----\n");

    String expectedSignature = sha1(content + SECRET);
    if (!signature.equals(expectedSignature)) {
      throw new SignedFileTamperedWith(fileName + " has been tampered with");
    }
    return content;
  }
}
```

Of course all they need to do is decompile your compiled source to see the secret, but it's an extra hoop they have to jump through.